# Can not log in to the Pebble account

Tags: nexus-4, pebble

I just received my Pebble Steel, and installed the app on my rooted Nexus 4.
However after I start the app, and click on "I have a pebble account", I only get a black screen with small blue letters saying:

https://auth.getpebble.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx...
Nothing happens if I click it.

What can I do? I removed the app, restarted the phone and installed it again, but this did not help.

The phone is rooted, SuperSU is installed, but the pebble app does not ask for any privileges.

Comment: Contact the app maker?

Comment: I tried 2 days ago. No response yet, so I hoped someone else in the community had the same problem, and probably a solution.